# Unknow effect in XUbuntu and Ubuntu: moving the mouse, the screen is moving around

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, screen

I do not know how I have just activated the (unwanted) feature. As I move the mouse, the screen is moving too all around. Is there a way of deactivating it? Unfortunately, it happens sometimes

**Temporary Walkaround**: I just turn-off the workstation and turn-on it again. The effect disappears. However, I would like to avoid this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution found:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse-Wheel-Forward</kbd> will zoom in on the entire desktop.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse-Wheel-Back</kbd> will zoom out and stop at normal size.

**Attention**: I was playing around with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and, thus, the trick does not work. The right key for this problem is <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

It seems that there is the same feature also in Ubuntu (based on Gnome). The answer comes from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266999).

To disable desktop zoom in XUbuntu, go `Settings` → `Settings Editor` → `xfwm4` → `zoom_desktop` and uncheck it.